# VMWare Workstation: Audio distorted (Windows 7 guest and Windows 7 host)

Tags: windows-7, audio, vmware-workstation

I use VMWare Workstation 14. Guest: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate; host: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. The audio coming from the guest is often distorted. What could the issue be?

I tried https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2012007:

> To adjust the speaker configuration on your virtual machine:
>
> 1. Navigate to Start > Control Panel and select Hardware and Sound.
> 2. Click Sound.
> 3. Select  Speakers and then click Properties.
> 4. Navigate to the Advanced tab.
> 5. Select 24 bit, 44100 Hz (Studio Quality) or higher, using the dropdown menu.
> 6. Click Apply, then click OK.
> 7. Restart your virtual machine.
>
> The audio output should now sound better.

This helps slightly.

> Edit the .vmx file of the virtual machine and delete the entry given  below:
>
> ```
> sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
> ```

This helps quite a bit.

However, the sound is still often distorted. It seems that whenever some process uses a bit of CPU on the guest, the sound  become distorted. I tried to increase the priority of the VM (by changing the priority of the VM process in the host), but it did not improve the audio.

Comment: This is very common in VMs, and I've never been able to solve it.

Comment: @SamRueby same here, I still have the issue.